# How to render a boolean value in an array with condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what I'm trying to do is to render every item of the array with the certified value next to it.

```
const ShoppingList= ()=> {
return (
    <ul>
        {itemList.map((item, index) => (
             <li key={`${item}-${index}`}>{ item }


                 key={ item.id }
                     {itemList.isCertified ? <span>Est certifié</span> : <span>n'est pas ceritfié</span>}
                 </li>


        ))}
    </ul>

)
}

export default ShoppingList
```

`isCertified` is a boolean value in each item of my array

```
const itemList = [
{
    name : 'chargeur',
    id: '5E034',
    isCertified:  true
},
{
    name: 'téléphone',
    id: "5E033",
    isCertified : true
},
{
    name: 'coque',
    id: "5E055",
    isCertified : true
},
{
    name: 'cable',
    id: "5E333",
    isCertified: false
}

]
export default itemList
```

I have this error :

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {name, id, isCertified}). If you meant to render a collection of
> children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written `{ item }` in your code (Just after the opening `li` tag). React cannot render objects directly in the DOM. That's why its giving you that error. Just remove it and things will work.
If you do want to render the entire object in the DOM, you can use `JSON.stringify(item)`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting key as object which is `item` and have written `{item}` in your code and in your map also there is issue.

This code will solve your issue

```
const ShoppingList= ()=> {
return (
    <ul>
        {itemList.map(item => (
             <li key={`${item.name}-${item.id}`}> // if your id is not unique

                     {item.isCertified ? <span>Est certifié</span> : <span>n'est pas ceritfié</span>}
                 </li>


        ))}
    </ul>

)}
```